# Failed opening 'SiteTest: Firefox.php' when running Yii Functional Test

Tags: php, selenium, yii, phpunit

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'SiteTest: Firefox.php' for inclusion 
... \yii\framework\YiiBase.php on line 418
```

Yii v1.1.10
PHPUnit v3.6.10
PHPUnit_Selenium v 1.2.6

I get this error when trying to run the example on the book "Agile Web Development with Yii 1.1 and PHP5" I kind of feel that there is a problem with the phrase `SiteTest:`, it shouldn't be there. But, how do I fix this?

**UPDATE (SOLVED):**
Apparently, the problem is not the warning shown above, but there is another error down the road. It says that "curl_init()" is undefined. I already enabled the php_curl extension, but the PHP from CLI is not using the same .ini file as the apache one. So, after I enabled the php_curl in the CLI version of the ini, it works fine now (still giving the warning, but the test is running).

Comment: Please show applocation.log and your php code

Comment: What is the actual example code?

Comment: I'm not sure what to show here, it's generated by the framework. I only run the command `phpunit functional/SiteTest.php`. Anything specific that you want me to show?

Comment: Has Selenium been installed properly?

Comment: @Sam, I think so. I can start the selenium server without error.

Comment: And it starts a browser properly?

Comment: @Sam, no, it doesn't start the browser at all.

Comment: Sounds like a problem. Try starting up Selenium in a non-headless mode.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11970/discussion-between-phelios-and-sam)

Comment: @Phelios has your question resolved mate??

Comment: @RajatSinghal, yes. It turned out that the warning doesn't do anything. Read my update above.

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds how to get rid of the warnings on [Yii Framework Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30511-firefoxphp-faild-to-include-in-yiibase/).

One of them involves editing PHPUnit core file `Framework/TestSuite.php` to supress warnings: put `@` in front of `method_exists($this->name, 'setUpBeforeClass')` [posted by Dmitriy K.](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30511-firefoxphp-faild-to-include-in-yiibase/page__p__148261#entry148261)

The other is more portable and right one. It is to comment browser lines in phpunit.xml:

```
    <selenium>
    <!--        <browser name="Internet Explorer" browser="*iexplore" />-->
    <!--        <browser name="Firefox" browser="*firefox" />-->
    </selenium>
```

And put into test script:

```
    parent::setUp();
    $this->setBrowser('*iexplore');
    $this->setBrowserUrl(TEST_BASE_URL);
```

[posted by Vitalets](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/30511-firefoxphp-faild-to-include-in-yiibase/page__p__149323#entry149323)

Answer (score 0):

Displaying of those warnings depends on php.ini settings:

```
error_reporting
display errors
```

if you don`t want to display this warnings you must set

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING | E_STRICT)
```

or

```
ini_set('display_errors','off');
```

directives in WebTestCase.php

and don`t switch off error logging to file to save && check errors

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue while trying to test my app.

You should download and start selenium server 
http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.22.0.jar

The warning will stay there, but the test will start!